# MongoDB reference using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to reference one model to other with Mongoose doing this:

//product model

```
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

   id: {type: Number, unique: true, required: 'product_id'},
   sku: {type: String, unique: true, required: 'product_sku'},
   name: {type: String, required: 'product_name'},
   short_description: {type: String},
   details: [{
      type: String
   }],
   categories: [{
      type: String
   }, {min: 1, max: 5}],

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('products', productSchema);
```

//order model

```
var orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

   id: {type: String, unique: true},
   date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
   products_sold: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'products'},

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('orders', orderSchema);
```

I've already created a product with id: 1:

```
"_id": ObjectId('55a1ce54b058d142051ca61d'),
"id": 1,
"sku": "p0001",
"name": "test1",
"short_description": "test",
//etc
```

If I do:

```
   var newOrder = new Order({
      id: 'order001',
      products_sold: 1,
      //etc
   });

   newOrder.save(function(err, data) {
      if(err){
         console.log(err);
      }else{
         console.log(data);
      }
   });
```

It fails with error:

```
  message: 'orders validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors: 
   { products_sold: 
      { [CastError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "1" at path "products_sold"]
```

How can I have products_sold in my order filled with product data that has id 1?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying that the `products_sold` field is of type ObjectId, but you are trying to set a `Number` as its value.  In order to store references to documents in other collections, you must store the `_id` of the referenced document, not an arbitrary id field that you have in the Schema.  You will either need to change the type for `_id` in your products database to use integers (and then manually specify what that _id field's value is when creating a new product), or you need to store the product's `_id` value in the order document's `product_sold` field.

Response to comment:

Here is updated code for specifying your own unique `_id` field:

**Product Model**

```
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

   _id: {type: Number, unique: true, required: 'product_id'},
   sku: {type: String, unique: true, required: 'product_sku'},
   name: {type: String, required: 'product_name'},
   short_description: {type: String},
   details: [String],
   categories: [{
      type: String
      min: 1, 
      max: 5
   }],

}, {_id: false});

module.exports = mongoose.model('products', productSchema);
```

In the productSchema, you will see that there is an `_id` specified, and it is set to `required`, and has no `default` value.  This should make it so that Mongo will use whatever `Number` you specify as it's _id.

Comment: I understand but I dont know how to implement it, can you please give me an example?

Comment: @mdv Do you **need** a separate `id` field for the product, or are you just specifying an arbitrary `id` to each product? I will provide you an answer on how to do it, but it depends whether you need that extra `id` field, or, if its just an arbitrary number, is it ok for you to use the unique `_id` field generated by Mongo?

Comment: Im using 'id' field because my lack of knowledge of Mongo models, if i use _id field I can't manually specify id for products, which one is the best? how can I retrieve data if I dont know the _id field. Thanks Matthew

Comment: @mdv How are you finding out the `id` of the product already?

Comment: Didn't code the route yet, but my idea is to show products for category on a view and the user select that ID from front end to construct the search query, so I guess that its the same to use _id

Comment: @mdv I uypdated the schema in my answer.  That Schema will work if you want to ue custom numbers for the _id.  However, if you are adding products to a database that do not have a custom id field already (which they probably wouldn't unless you are getting the product data elsewhere), you should probably just use the build in functionality of using ObjectIds from Mongo.  In this case, when you send a list of products to the client to choose from, and they send back the product they want to purchase, you just reference the _id field automatically generated.  This will be sent to the client

Comment: @mdv initially when you send the list of products, and you can send it back from the client when they choose the product to purchase.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass objectId of the product in product_sold , rather than number.

Comment: Can this be done with my id rather _id? can you please give me an example?